# Simple Azure C# Server for sending, receiveng and running .exe

Tags: c#, azure, client-server, cloud, file-transfer

Here is my case:

- Azure Cloud
- MS VS 2013
- Old Fortran .exe for some computations - let's call it solver with plain text files for input and output.

I configured virtual machine in Azure for executing solver.exe. Now i want to develop simple client and server apps with C# or any other language/tool from MS stack to use in this scenario:

- Client sets some settings, generates files and sends them to the virtual machine in the cloud.
- Server receives this data, runs solver.exe and sends some results back.
- Client saves results on local machine.

So what do I use to write server - C# or some script language? Should I write file transfer from the scratch? 
Any links to relevant guidelines are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do is create a service using WCF (Windows Communication Foundation).

Here some useful links:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2013/10/18/getting-started-with-wcf-windows-communication-foundation-running-and-debugging-quickly.aspx

Then to consume your service, just create a console application for example and add a service reference to your wcf service.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx